# Does sql nvarchar length matter?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm looking at a table set up as `nvarchar(50)` The contents are only ever 2 characters or null. Is it important to change it? What's the optimal type if it's often used in an IN clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not use `nvarchar(2)` to ensure that only 2 characters ever are written? It's a constraint, there to ensure that the data conforms to an expectation.

Also if you know the values will only ever be `ASCII` then use `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`.

Finally, the length constraint will not have any affect on `IN` clause assuming that all the values never exceed the length of 2.

Comment: I should have specified. I'm most curious about performance. Does having a too-long field affect speed in a where clause, for example?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - What matters is the value in the field. Having a field length of 2000 and storing 2 characters will have no affect with a `where` clause. What would have an affect is the number of records, how you are comparing, and indexes (if they are there, how they are structured, are they fragmented). The only real exclusion to this is length `max` as the values could span pages in to an overlfow in which case I am not sure how any indexing would work but this only affects values that also exceed 4000 (i believe).

Comment: Is there and advantage/disadvantage to using a null vs an empty string value for this scenario?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - not that I am aware of. Ouitside of that When/if to use `null` and also empty string is usually tied to a business constraint(s).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `nchar(2)` for unicode or `char(2)` for non unicode if the size is always 2 or `null`.

Using an oversized variable-width column impacts the memory grant and row size estimates, as SQL Server will assume that each row holds a value that is half the declared column size; while this may not be a significant factor with a width of `50` it makes a more noticeable difference on larger sizes.

Reference:

- [Performance Myths : Oversizing string columns - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/06/sql-plan/performance-myths-oversizing-strings)

Comment: That's a great article you linked to. Given that questions in SO are typically simplified for posting, answers which cover the broader topic are a lot more valuable than just covering the question literally.